# Generate a .xsl file from an encodeString

Tags: python, email, xslt, odoo, email-attachments

I have an encoded string (excel_file) and I want to generate a xsl file from this string.

Is it possible to  generate a .xsl file adding a code only in my .py file without saving this file in local, because I want to attache this file to a mail.

```
att_id = self.env['ir.attachment'].create({

                    'name': 'My name',
                    'type': 'binary',
                    'datas':excel_file,
                    'datas_fname': 'Myname.xsl',
                    'res_model': 'print.invoice.cron',
                    'res_id': self.id,
                    'mimetype': 'text/csv'

                    })


                tools.email_send(email_from='sending@test.fr',
                            email_to=['recive@gmail.com'],
                            subject='Some subject',
                            body=att_id)
```

I'm reciving the id of attachement,but not the file.And there is no attache attribute for email_send()

Comment: You can send email using email template and can add attachment there. Please let me know if you need help with the code.

Comment: @HimanshuSharma yes of course.But I don't need to create templates because it's in cron,no?

Comment: Email templates are simply a content templates for email which you are sending. You can use force send true if you don't want to wait for cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's my suggestion:

```
att_id = self.env['ir.attachment'].create({

                    'name': 'My name',
                    'type': 'binary',
                    'datas':excel_file,
                    'datas_fname': 'Myname.xsl',
                    'res_model': 'print.invoice.cron',
                    'res_id': self.id,
                    'mimetype': 'text/csv'

                    })
template = self.env.ref(
                        'module_name.email_template', False)
ctx = dict(
                            default_model=self._name,
                            default_res_id=self.id,
                            default_use_template=bool(template),
                            default_template_id=template.id,
                            default_composition_mode='comment',
                            default_email_to=email,
                            default_lang=self.env.user.partner_id.lang,
                            default_attachment_ids=[(6, 0, att_id.ids)],
                        )
self.env['mail.template'].browse(template.id).with_context(
                            ctx).send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
```

Code for template creation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <odoo>
        <data noupdate="1">
            <record id="email_template" model="mail.template">
                <field name="name">Template Name</field>
                <field name="model_id" ref="module_name.model_your_model"/>
                <field name="email_to">${ctx.get('default_email_to')}</field>
                <field name="subject">Subject</field>
                <field name="body_html" type="html">
    <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px;">
Email body
</p>
        Thanks
    </div>
                </field>
                <field name="lang">${ctx.get('default_lang')}</field>
                <field name="user_signature" eval="True"/>
                <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            </record>

        </data>
    </odoo>
```

Please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: I tested it and for this line                             default_template_id=template.id,
I got an error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
I think it's because of                 template = self.env.ref('print.invoice.cron, False)
I tested with template = self.env.ref('print.invoice.cron.email_template, False) but I got the same result

Comment: default_template_id=template.id This line indicates you have to pass id of your template. Create a custom template in your module the pass the id .

Comment: I got the same error.Can you sent me please an example of that,I tried :
 <record id="view_print_invoice_cron_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">print.invoice.cron.form</field>
            <field name="model">print.invoice.cron</field>
   <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Print Invoice ">
    </form>
   </field>

Comment: I've already updated my answer with example of template creation. Please check.

Comment: ok, and I must put the template in view,with my cron templates?